# OnDocumentMouseMove three.js not working

Tags: javascript, mouse, mousemove

I am not at all experienced with three.js but I am trying to create a camera effect equal to this one: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_colors

I was trying to use the following code to read out the mouse positions and apply those, (they do it the same way in the example). 
For the sake of trying to find out where the problem is I put in "camera.positon.x = 1000" to see if it works, which it does not. Now I don't know where the problem lies but I just can't get the mouse to work.

```
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );
    camera.position.x = 10000;
}
```

(I don't want to use Orbit Controls by the way)
Thanks in advance

Below is the entire code

```
<script>

    var renderer, camera, controls, scene, mesh1, mesh2;

function init(){
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});   
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000044);        

    scene = new THREE.Scene();        
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);    
    camera.position.set(0,0,750);        

    resize();
    window.onresize = resize;

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.9);
    scene.add(light);

    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
    scene.add(light2);
    light2.position.set(0,8,75);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xFF1111,
    });
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh1.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh1);
    mesh1.position.set(0,0,50);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x11FF11,
    });
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh2.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh2);
    mesh2.position.set(0,0,0);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x1111FF,
    });
    mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh3.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh3);
    mesh3.position.set(0,0, -50);

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
}

function resize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
    mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );
    camera.position.x = 10000;
}    

function render() {    
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    camera.position.x += 0.5;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
}

init(); render();    

</script>
```

Comment: Did you notice that [line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/3cb51d868ee279be373815de592fc072deffc82c/examples/webgl_geometry_colors.html#L183) there?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply, I did not notice the line, but with it added it did not change anything. (I will edit the post)

Comment: A good practice is to set breakpoints, or even console logs. If you are never calling that function you can't expect the stuff in it to happen... This s not a three.js related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables `windowHalfX` and `windowHalfY` are not defined in your code.

If the position of the camera should depend on the mouse position, then you have to manipulate the camera position by the change of the mouse position. This means you have to calculate the difference of the current mouse position and the previous mouse position.

If you want to calculate a manipulation of the position, dependent on the position of the mouse in relation to the center of the canvas, then the code should look somehow like this:

```
var prevDeltaX = 0, prevDeltaY = 0;
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY;
    var deltaX = (window.innerWidth / 2 - mouseX);
    var deltaY = (mouseY - window.innerHeight / 2);
    camera.position.x += deltaX - prevDeltaX;
    camera.position.y += deltaY - prevDeltaY;
    prevDeltaX = deltaX; prevDeltaY = deltaY; 
}
```

See the snippet:

```js
var renderer, camera, controls, scene, mesh1, mesh2;

function init(){
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.getElementById('myCanvas'), antialias: true});   
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000044);        

    scene = new THREE.Scene();        
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(15, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 3000);    
    camera.position.set(0,0,750);        

    resize();
    window.onresize = resize;

    var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.9);
    scene.add(light);

    var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
    scene.add(light2);
    light2.position.set(0,8,75);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0xFF1111,
    });
    mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh1.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh1);
    mesh1.position.set(0,0,50);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x11FF11,
    });
    mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh2.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh2);
    mesh2.position.set(0,0,0);

    var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30, 30, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x1111FF,
    });
    mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material);
    mesh3.rotation.x = -0.05;

    scene.add(mesh3);
    mesh3.position.set(0,0, -50);

    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
}

function resize() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

var prevDeltaX = 0, prevDeltaY = 0;
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    var mouseX = event.clientX;
    var mouseY = event.clientY;
    var deltaX = (window.innerWidth / 2 - mouseX);
    var deltaY = (mouseY - window.innerHeight / 2);
    camera.position.x += deltaX - prevDeltaX;
    camera.position.y += deltaY - prevDeltaY;
    prevDeltaX = deltaX; prevDeltaY = deltaY; 
}    

function render() {    
    requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    //camera.position.x += 0.5;
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
}

init(); render();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you again, you never seize to dissapoint!
Would you happen to know how to make this a bit more smooth, (kinda like vSync in games) or something similar?